# Solving $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-2\alpha|x|}\cos^2(x)\,dx$

Tags: integration

I'd like some help solving the integral

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2 \, \alpha \, |x|} \cdot \cos^2(x) \; \, dx 
$$

with $\alpha > 0$

I just assumed 'integration-by-parts' was the way to go, but the first part
of the product alone ($e^{-2\alpha|x|}$) gets quite confusing. Is there any trick to making it stay manageable?

The absolute-value in the exponent is confusing me, too - do I have to differentiate between cases every time?

Comment: Use the symmetry to get rid of the absolute value.

Comment: what is $\alpha$?

Comment: Sorry, α > 0. It's just a parameter -> I want the solution in terms of α.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:
$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-2\alpha|x|}\cos^2(x)\,dx = 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-2\alpha x}\cos^2 x\,dx =\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-2\alpha x}(1+\cos(2x))\,dx$$
hence:
$$ I = \frac{1}{2\alpha}+\frac{\alpha}{2(\alpha^2+1)}$$
since:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\beta x}\,dx = \frac{1}{\beta},\qquad \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\beta x}\cos x\,dx = \frac{\beta}{1+\beta^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an even function, you can only do it for x > 0. Cos^2 ( x ) = ( 1 - cos2x )/ 2, and exp( -2ax )* cos (2x) is the real part of exp( -2ax + 2ix ). Remain is easy.